# How do I extract the content of quoted strings from the output of a shell command

Tags: shell

The following shell command returns an output with 3 items:

```
cred="$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::01234567899:role/test --role-session-name s3-access-example --query '[Credentials.AccessKeyId, Credentials.SecretAccessKey, Credentials.SessionToken]')"
```

echo $cred returns the following output:

```
[ "ASRDTDRSIJGISGDT", "trttr435", "DF/////eraesr43" ]
```

How do I retrieve the value between double quotes? For example, trttr435
How to achieve this? Use regex? or other options?

Comment: Can you do `echo "$cred"` and paste it? and which shell are you using? It would be helpful for the contributors to test their answers on and lastly did you make an effort trying to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IFS=', ' credArray=(`echo "$cred" | tr -d '"[]'`)
```

Simple as ... that

**Testing**

```
cred='[ "ASRDTDRSIJGISGDT", "trttr435", "DF/////eraesr43" ]'
IFS=', ' credArray=(`echo "$cred" | tr -d '"[]'`)
for i in "${credArray[@]}"; do echo "[$i]"; done
echo "2nd parameter is ${credArray[1]}"
```

**Output**

```
[ASRDTDRSIJGISGDT]
[trttr435]
[DF/////eraesr43]
2nd parameter is trttr435
```

*Tested on Mac OS bash and CentOS bash*

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite catch if the `[` and `]` are in the `$cred` or not, or what is your expected output but this will return everything between double quotes:

```
$ awk '{while(match($0,/"[^"]+"/)){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}}' file
ASRDTDRSIJGISGDT
trttr435
DF/////eraesr43
```

You could and probably would like to:

```
$ echo "$cred" | awk ... # add above script here
```

**Edit**: If you just want to get the quoted string from second field (`$2`):

```
$ awk -F, '{match($2,/"[^"]+"/);print substr($2,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}' file
trttr435
```

or even:

```
$ awk -F, '{gsub(/^[^"]+"|"[^"]*$/,"",$2);print $2}' file
```

Comment: That's very close to what I am looking for. Is it possible to return the individual value? For example I only want to return the 2nd value?

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. I ran this command "echo "$cred" | awk '{while(match($0,/"[^"]+"/)){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}}' file" and its returning "awk: can't open file file"

Comment: I have never used awk before. I tried all your commands and getting the error "awk: can't open file file" any idea why?

Comment: And if you pipe to awk, remove the `file` after awk. You can't pipe to awk AND open a file at the same time.

Comment: Your last command works for me, echo "$cred" | awk -F, '{gsub(/^[^"]+"|"[^"]*$/,"",$2);print $2}'  -The problem is it doesnt eliminate the bracket and space. I am getting "[ ASRDTDRSIJGISGDT" and " DF/////eraesr43 ]"

Answer (score 0):

Or use python, because the content of cred is already a valid python array:

```
#!/bin/bash

cred='[ "ASRDTDRSIJGISGDT", "trttr435", "DF/////eraesr43" ]'

python-script() {
    local INDEX=$1
    echo "arr=$cred"
    echo "print(arr[$INDEX])"
}

item() {
    local INDEX=$1
    python-script "$INDEX" | python
}


echo "item1=$(item 1)"
echo "item2=$(item 2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another crude but effective way of extracting the values you need would be to use awk with " as the split delimiter. The valid positions, in this case, would be $2, $4, $6

```
OUT="[ \"ASRDTDRSIJGISGDT\", \"trttr435\", \"DF/////eraesr43\" ]"
echo $OUT | awk -F '"' '{print $4}'
```

I would advise you to use python if you need to do a lot of string parsing.